# Can't reach a site in localhost after rebooting ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, localhost, cvat

I tried to reach localhost after installing CVAT using docker-compose. I successfully run it after the installation, but after I reboot the computer, it shows that the site can't be reached.
What can I do?

Comment: From where do you want to reach localhost? And which localhost do you mean? The Host where the Docker Containers run on, or the localhost from inside a Docker Container?  It would be helpful if you add the docker-compose file here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you re-start the container (`docker-compose up -d`) after rebooting your system? You will need to do that after restarting your computer. To be safe, do `docker-compose stop` first.